# Cleaning up MSrepl_errors, SQL Server Replication

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, transactional-replication

Our MSrepl_errors table is around 15GB and got records from the beginning of time.
What is the correct way of cleaning up this table.  Do we simply delete from it?

**Edit**
The distribution agent clean up is already running.
[image]

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There a stored procedure named [sp_MShistory_cleanup] called by the job [Agent history clean up: distribution].

That job should take its params from the following setting:

[image: Distribution properties]

Check if your job is enabled and running as scheduled.

Later edit: mentioned that job because its stored procedure has this following piece of code inside:

```
-- Delete MSrepl_error entries
DELETE FROM MSrepl_errors 
    WHERE time <= @replerr_cutoff 
    OPTION(MAXDOP 1)
SELECT @error = @@error, @num_replerror_rows = @@rowcount
IF @error <> 0
    GOTO FAILURE
```

This should handle the errors cleanup. I checked several of my instances and they all have only new errors, not old, so I suppose the job is also doing this part correctly.

Can you run the procedure manually and see if it runs correctly?

Comment: Sorry, should have mentioned, I have already checked that and the job is running.  I am thinking that MSrepl_errors  is not part of the cleanup?

Comment: See updated answer pls, it should handle this part.

Answer (score -1):

MSrepl_errors use @replerr_cutoff = dateadd(hour, -@history_retention -30*24, getdate()) --> cleanup MSrepl_erros table with historyretention + 30 days. Rest of the table used historyretention to delete rows.